# Error Failed to commit a transaction to the db: operation not supported

Tags: monerod, synchronization, error-log, lmdb

[image]Since the last fork, I have been unable to sync my monero nodes.  I have tried from multiple machines and redownloaded the blockchain entirely, However, I still get the following results.

Is anyone familiar with this?
The mounted drive has 500+GB free space on NTFS partition.

Thanks!
The picture taken is of my monitor with error showing.

src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:72 Failed to commit a transaction to the db: Operation not supported
src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3598 Exception in cleanup_handle_incoming_blocks: Failed to commit a transaction

Answer (score 2):

The default ntfs driver in Linux doesn't support writes. NTFS support on Linux is generally pretty awful.

Comment: On my Ubuntu Laptop, I run into the same error though.  This is one reason I moved to raspian.  Is the root of the issue a corrupt DB in both cases?  I would think so but the chances would be slim I would have thought..

Comment: There's no DB corruption here at all. Your OS doesn't support NTFS in read/write mode. Use ext4 or xfs instead.